# calculating correlation coefficient by batch condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, correlation

I am trying to use corr() function to calculate the correlation coefficient of a dataframe.

The dataframe that I have contains approximately 200 variables with 50,000,000 rows.
I am keep getting **memory error** when I run `df.corr(method='spearman')`

Is there a code where I can split the calculations to avoide the memory error?

For instance, lets say I have variable A,B,C,D
The correlation pairs would be

A,B   A,C   A,D

B,A   B,C   B,D

and etc.

I was wandering if I could create a loop for .corr() function to split the calculation for **'A'** pairs first, then **'B'** pair and later concatenate to form the matrix.

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: Couple of things you can try, 1. You could probably read the dataframe in chunks and then compute the correlation. A solution here is outlined https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717513/python-numpy-corrcoef-memory-error
2. The other option is to use `Dask`. My suggestion is to use `Dask`. It's specifically designed to be used for large datasets and low memory. You can convert your dataset to/from `Pandas` with ease. If needed, you can even switch over to `Dask` 100%.
https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.corr

Comment: If I read the df as chunks and calculate the correlations, will it still give the same output as if I were to run it as a whole df?

Comment: I'm not sure about that because I haven't tried it. I've worked with `Dask` before so I can vouch for it. The other good thing about `Dask` is you get to keep most of your code the same. The syntax is pretty much the same as `Pandas` so there's going to be very little changes to your code.